# Update a label's text without needing to call the label's NotifyPropertyChanged from every property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to implement a WPF form (showing employee data) so that when there is a change in any field, the head label (FullnameTitle) has an asterisk.  E.g. John Smith*

I'm using MVVM, with a ViewModel base that also tracks changes.  I have also opted to keep Model properties seperate (i.e. NotifyPropertyChanged is in the ViewModel)

Below is what I currently have.  I know that to update the head label I need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("FullnameTitle")` on all form fields.

My question is, is there a better way, one that does not require calling it for every field? (My full employee form has over 50 fields)

**Window XAML**

```
<Label x:Name="HeadLabel" Content="{Binding FullnameTitle, FallbackValue='Employee Details'}" FontSize="28"/>
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Employee ID"/>
    <TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Employee.EmployeeId}"/>
    <Label Content="First name"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Firstname, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
    <Label Content="Surname"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Surname, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
    <Label Content="DOB"/>
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Dob, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
    <Label Content="Age"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class EmployeeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }

    public string FullnameTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}{2}", Employee.Firstname, Employee.Surname, IsDirty ? "*" : "");
        }
    }

    public string Firstname
    {
        get
        {
            return Employee.Firstname;
        }
        set
        {
            Employee.Firstname = ApplyPropertyChange(Employee.Firstname, value, "Firstname");
        }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get
        {
            return Employee.Surname;
        }
        set
        {
            Employee.Surname = ApplyPropertyChange(Employee.Surname, value, "Surname");
        }
    }

    public DateTime? Dob
    {
        get
        {
            return Employee.Dob;
        }
        set
        {
            Employee.Dob = ApplyPropertyChange(Employee.Dob, value, "Dob");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return Employee.Age;  // Age calculation done in EmployeeModel
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModelBase**

```
abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Changes { get; private set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        Changes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return Changes.Count > 0; }
    }

    public T ApplyPropertyChange<T>(T field, T value, string caller)
    {
        // Only do this if the value changes
        if (field == null || !field.Equals(value))
        {
            string propertyName = caller;  // Property name

            field = value;                 // Set the value

            Changes[propertyName] = value; // Change tracking

            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName); // Notify change
        }

        return field;
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are raising the event only when a property is changed, aren't you? What is your issue?

Comment: I'm wanting to see if there's a better way than needing to add `NotifyPropertyChanged("FullnameTitle")` on every binded field property.  And since FullnameTitle label only requires updating after the first form's field value change... is there a way to update the label just the once, and still not require `NotifyPropertyChanged("FullnameTitle")` on every binded field property (wrapped in an if statement)

Answer (score -1):

Use events.

In your view model subscribe to `PropertyChanged`:

**EmployeeViewModel.cs**

```
class EmployeeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public EmployeeViewModel()
  {
    this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(this.FullnameTitle));
  }

  ...
}
```

But be careful. Calling the `PropertyChanged` event invocator `NotifyPropertyChanged` for a property that
itself raises the `PropertyChanged` event will lead to an infinite recursion.

### Alternative better approach

Use a multi binding `IMultiValueConverter` that is triggered by `ViewModelBase.IsDirty`:

**IsDirtyToStringConverter.cs**

```
class IsDirtyToStringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (values[0] is EmployeeViewModel viewModel && values[1] is bool modelIsDirty)
    {
      return string.Format("{0} {1}{2}", 
        viewModel.Firstname, 
        viewModel.Surname, 
        modelIsDirty 
          ? "*" 
          : string.Empty);
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**Window.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
  <IsDirtyToStringConverter x:Keyy="IsDirtyToStringConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock x:Name="HeadLabel" FallbackValue='Employee Details'}" FontSize="28" >
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsDirtyToStringConverter}"
                  FallbackValue='Employee Details'>
       <Binding Path="." />           
       <Binding Path="IsDirty" />
     </MultiBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
<StackPanel>
  <Label Content="Employee ID"/>
  <TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Employee.EmployeeId}"/>
  <Label Content="First name"/>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Firstname}"/>
  <Label Content="Surname"/>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
  <Label Content="DOB"/>
  <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Dob}"/>
  <Label Content="Age"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. I changed it to do what you've suggested.  But the label doesn't update when editing a field without any NotifyPropertyChanged, and throws a System.StackOverflow exception when DOB updates which calls NotifyPropertyChanged("Age")

Comment: `NotifyPropertyChanged` is required. What do you mean? Binding requires the `PropertyChanged` event. If you are sure that `NotifyPropertyChanged("Age")` causes the exception, then check the callstack. Also it would better to explicitly set the `Age`. Let the `CalculateAge()` return the age and the assign it to the `Age` property which should be a simple auto-property. It also reads better.

Comment: I added a cleaner approach using multi binding. The label binds to `IsDirty`. When `IsDirty` changed in the view model the label will update. You don't need to bother with `NotifyPropertyChanged` anymore. But also set the `Age` explicitly (make it a auto-property.